# Strange <ul> spacing in different email clients

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm working on an HTML email using MailChimp. In the email, I have two separate unorganized lists with a break in between them.

The emails look good in Gmail and Mail (Mac) but the spacing is really wonky in Outlook. I initially used a break and the space was very wide. Then I used a `<p>` tag and it looked great in Gmail and Mail, but in Outlook there wasn't any space between the two lists.

This is the code used:

```
<ul style="line-height: 20.8000011444092px;">
<li><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">How many times you&rsquo;ve checked your blood glucose in a day and how many strips you have left. What&rsquo;s really cool is when you only have 10 days of supplies remaining,&nbsp;we&rsquo;ll prompt you to approve a reorder through the XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup></span></span><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">&nbsp;blood glucose meter. All you have to do is say &ldquo;YES&rdquo; and we&rsquo;ll ship more supplies right to your home!</span></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">How many steps you&rsquo;ve taken if you&rsquo;re using the pedometer function&nbsp;on XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup>.</span></span></li>
```

It looks normal when put in here, but in Outlook the spacing is a good 2 inches. Any advice on how to fix my UL spacing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use margin: top right bottom left http://jsfiddle.net/bzpk57py/3/

```
<ul style="line-height: 20.8000011444092px;">
<li style="margin:0 0 20px 0;"><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">How many times you&rsquo;ve checked your blood glucose in a day and how many strips you have left. What&rsquo;s really cool is when you only have 10 days of supplies remaining,&nbsp;we&rsquo;ll prompt you to approve a reorder through the XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup></span></span><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">&nbsp;blood glucose meter. All you have to do is say &ldquo;YES&rdquo; and we&rsquo;ll ship more supplies right to your home!</span></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">How many steps you&rsquo;ve taken if you&rsquo;re using the pedometer function&nbsp;on XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup>.</span></span></li>
```

also you could use % instead of px

```
<ul style="line-height: 120%">
<li style="margin:0 0 4% 0"><span style="font-size:1em"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">How many times you&rsquo;ve checked your blood glucose in a day and how many strips you have left. What&rsquo;s really cool is when you only have 10 days of supplies remaining,&nbsp;we&rsquo;ll prompt you to approve a reorder through the XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup></span></span><span style="font-size:1em"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">&nbsp;blood glucose meter. All you have to do is say &ldquo;YES&rdquo; and we&rsquo;ll ship more supplies right to your home!</span></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size:1em;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">How many steps you&rsquo;ve taken if you&rsquo;re using the pedometer function&nbsp;on XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup>.</span></span></li>
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using two text blocks so Outlook wouldn't merge the two into one unorganized list, but adjusted the margins of each block. Worked like a charm!